# Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule fails on parameter 'source' that cannot be null (attempting to use -ServiceTag)

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to create access restrictions for Azure Web App from PowerShell, but the cmdlet Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule fails with the error message "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')". From what I can see there is no parameter 'source' that can be added to the cmdlet - any suggestions?

My code is as per below, but below has been stripped from actual names.

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule `
  -ResourceGroupName <my-resource-group> `
  -WebAppName <my-web-app-name> `
  -Name FrontDoorServiceTagRule `
  -Priority 100 `
  -Action Allow `
  -ServiceTag AzureFrontDoor.Backend `
  -HttpHeader @{'x-azure-fdid' = '<my-frontdoor-id>'}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Which `Az.Websites` version you are using? I am using   `2.5.0`

Comment: I'm on the same version - Az.Websites version 2.5.0

Comment: Have you tried to wrap all string params by `'`?

Comment: Yes, same result :-(

Comment: That's really weird :(

Comment: Three options to troubleshoot: 1. Just run the single command to make sure the error was caused by it. 2. Use `Get-Module` to make sure you used the correct powershell version 3.Try the command in [Azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

Comment: Update - someone has reported the same issue to Microsoft 11 days ago on GitHub https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14862

Comment: If you are using powershell 7, try to update it to the latest version https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14862#issuecomment-842276785), if you want to run the command in Azure DevOps pipeline AzurePowerShell task, you could use `AzurePowerShell@7`, to run the Powershell 7 script on DevOps, you could refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63806050/9455659).

> To run the Powershell 7 script on DevOps, you need to explicitly select the option to use Powershell core (v 7.0.3) in Azure DevOps. Powershell 6 onwards it is now known as Powershell core and is launched as pwsh.exe. PowerShell Core runs side-by-side with Windows PowerShell and by default when you are using the Powershell task on Azure DevOps it uses normal powershell (i.e. v 5.1). So, when running without this Powershell default to the normal powershell.exe which does not have this feature.
> We can enable Powershell core on Azure DevOps task using the checkbox Use Powershell Core under Advanced settings of the task and use the parallel feature.